# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<> above this _SomeWidget Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have problem with my provider. I have seen there is an other question about that but I didn't understand the answer... I am a beginner please be understanding with me =) I have followed a tutorial but I have made some mistakes. I have published my code on GitHub : https://github.com/Rianou20/App-test

and the screenshots :

[image: Error part 1]

[image: Error part 2]

[image: Debug Consol]

[image: Exception]

Thanks !

**Update** : I have put my `MultiProviders` in main.dart

Comment: this happen because yo didnt provide the context to  `_MyListItem`                       
 `itemBuilder: (context, index) => _MyListItem(index))` then you called provider inside the `_MyListItem`  which does not contain `context` that have provider

Comment: And how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: @ahmed can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `MultiProvider` to the `MyApp` not the Nav class, this happen because you called other Widget classes outside the `context` that contain the Provider Object, best way to do not get any provider error is to read [Provider Documment](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)